# How do I view vote counts?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

**I just got the below process to view vote counts.**

[image]

**But i think there is some bugs to show down vote**.

[image]

Previously there was 8 upvotes now its only shows 6 upvotes and no downvotes.

Little bit confuse.

Comment: I could not reproduce this as a bug - as @Clive responded, there are a few different reasons as to why a question score changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there are bugs with that score, I've never seen any and I use it many times a day.

If a question/answer previously had more or less up or down votes, one of the following could have happened:

- People have retracted their vote(s).
- One or more users have been removed, and the votes chalked off.

To directly answer your question:

> How do I view vote counts?

The way you're doing it is the correct (and only) way.

Comment: Thanks @Clive, I understand the second point but i can not cleared about the first point(People have retracted their vote(s)).

Comment: You can retract a vote within 5 minutes of voting, or when an edit has been made. Since there's been no edit made here, and assuming it definitely was on +8, either two people have retracted their votes within that initial 5 minute period, or, and I think more likely in this case. Though I'm not going into specifics :)